# How does Holy C differ from regular C?

Tags: programming, operating-system

The Temple OS operating system has been credited as one of the most impressive coding achievements ever done by a single coder.

It was done in Assembly and a variant of the C language called Holy C.

I would really be interested in how this language differs from standard C?

The story of Temple OS is woven with one mans struggle with mental health problems. Something that I believe all coders experience to a certain degree.

Maybe this question could be a small tribute to the man called Terry A Davis.

Comment: If this was an answer it would be a link only answer, so it's a comment. This article seems to give a flavour https://harrison.totty.dev/p/a-lang-design-analysis-of-holyc

Comment: "First released in 2005 as J Operating System, TempleOS was renamed in 2013 and was last updated in 2018. " This is retro?

Comment: @JeremyP The author of that link probably doesn't understand what a unit type is…

Comment: @TomasBy It's abandonware, historically notable, uses old-fashioned design principles… I think it's more retro than Windows 2000, despite being newer.

Comment: @user3840170 It might still need a few years to settle before being retro.

Comment: "The Temple OS operating system has been credited as one of the most impressive coding achievements ever done by a single coder." Well, similar things have been done by small groups (early Unix, Oberon), and it was small groups instead of a single coder because the people doing this happened to be sane, not crazy, and could collaborate. So it's nothing out of reach of a normal programmer with enough time, and the other examples are actually better designed.

Comment: *has been credited as one of the most impressive coding achievements ever done by a single coder*  - credited by whom?

Comment: “Variant of C”. Quite a distant cousin instead.

Comment: I'd never heard of Holy C so I did some quick googling and found this link on the Wayback Machine.  FWIW, https://web.archive.org/web/20170325000321/http://www.templeos.org/Wb/Doc/HolyC.html

Comment: @another-dave by the original programmer…

Comment: Technically abandonware since the author has since passed away, but any idea if the source was ever picked up by anyone?